# Is there a way to avoid class "discriminator"?

Tags: typescript

Not sure if "discriminator" is a right word here.
Consider following code:

```
abstract class A {
}

class A1 extends A {
}

class A2 extends A {
}

interface SomeMap {
  [key: string]: new (...args: any[]) => A;
}

class B<T extends SomeMap> {
  public test<K extends keyof T>(key: K, instance: InstanceType<T[K]>): void {}
}

const map = {
  a1: A1,
  a2: A2,
};

class C extends B<typeof map> {}

const c = new C();

c.test('a1', new A1()); // No errors from TS - good
c.test('a1', new A2()); // No errors from TS - bad, I want ts to error here!
```

And with "discriminator":

```
abstract class A {
  protected abstract discriminator: undefined;
}

class A1 extends A {
  protected discriminator: undefined;
}

class A2 extends A {
  protected discriminator: undefined;
}

interface SomeMap {
  [key: string]: new (...args: any[]) => A;
}

class B<T extends SomeMap> {
  public test<K extends keyof T>(key: K, instance: InstanceType<T[K]>): void {}
}

const map = {
  a1: A1,
  a2: A2,
};

class C extends B<typeof map> {}

const c = new C();

c.test('a1', new A1()); // No errors from TS - good
c.test('a1', new A2()); // TS error - good!
```

Is there any way to make it work while avoiding declaring "discriminator" prop in class that inherits from A? Just want to detect that A1 != A2 in TS.

Comment: You will be happiest if you learn to accept [structural typing](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-structural-typing).  Isn't there something actually different about the classes other than their names?  If not, then you need to [pretend there is](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-prevent-two-types-from-being-structurally-compatible), like you're doing with that [`protected`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#understanding-private) "discriminator".

Comment: Thanks! So it seems declaring protected prop on abstract class is only way of forcing classes extending it to have different "type" in TS.